# Is it possible to break a sata drive by plugging it into an esata port

Tags: hard-drive, sata, esata

The motherboard has two esata ports. After plugging in five sata drives in various sequences, three would no longer spin up.

I am wondering if the electrical differences would be enough to short them out.

@moab The drives were mounted internally in the case, and powered by the internal PSU, and connected by a standard sata (not esata) cable.  A number of different arrangements were tried, to try and identify the problem, so it isn't clear exactly what was plugged in where when they failed.

Comment: You might consider editing you question to include exactly how you connected them and what type of cable was used, or enclosure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highly unlikely.  More likely is static electricity toasting their circuit boards.

Comment: That is good.  I want to use these ports for standard sata drives, and was concerned I was breaking them by using them this way.

Comment: I got 5 drives plug in on a computer also, along with four more plug into a RAID card.  You should be ok.  Just get a good surge protector.

Comment: Ooh.  Are you up to RAID 10 with that setup?

Comment: Nope.  JBOD. Just a Bunch of Drives.